# Python 3: Making a new line in a variable

Tags: python, variables, line, new-operator

I'm currently trying to make an ASCII map via python using segments of walls. I got it to work in print() but I'm a bit new and don't know how to store it to a variable.

If I invoke the variable, it prints the list with no line breaks. If I assign a variable to a print, it works, but prints it all first before I want it to.

Any solutions? Can I format the initial a1_map list to create the new lines?

Here's what I have:

````
north_exit = ' ___|   |___'
north_no_exit = ' ___________'
south_exit = ' ```|  |``` '
mid_no_exit = '|           |'
top_WandE_exit = '\u2143           L'
top_W_exit = '\u2143           |'
top_E_exit = '|           L'
mid_WandE_exit = '    (\u00B0.\u00B0)      '
mid_W_exit ='    (\u00B0.\u00B0)   |'
mid_E_exit ='|   (\u00B0.\u00B0)    '
lower_W_exit = '\u02E5           |'
lower_WandE_exit = 'T           T'
lower_E_exit = '|           T'
current_room = 'the crew quarters'


a1_map = print(north_no_exit,'\n' + top_E_exit,'\n' + mid_E_exit,'\n' + lower_E_exit, '\n' +south_exit, '\n'+ 'You are in',current_room+'.')
````

I could just type:

```
print(north_no_exit,'\n' + top_E_exit,'\n' + mid_E_exit,'\n' + lower_E_exit, '\n' +south_exit, '\n'+ 'You are in',current_room+'.')
```

each time. However I want to format it so I can just type:

```
print(a1_map)
```

As an example, the list output without `print()` looks like:

(' ___________', '\n|           L', '\n|   (°.°)    ', '\n|           T', '\n `|  |` ', '\nYou are in', 'the crew quarters.')

I would like it to look like (as an example):

````
 ___________ 
|           L 
|   (°.°)     
|           T 
 ```|  |```
````

(EDIT: Sorry, trying to make it look like a box but I cant even do it on here!)

Comment: `a1_map = print(...)` print() doesn't return the message printed; it always returns None.  So a1_map will be None here..

Comment: Thanks Paul! I was only 25 edits away from getting it to work! haha

Comment: just remove the print() function from the a1_map variable. then it will store the value instead of returning None from the print().

Comment: I'm not clear on what your input data actually *is*. If it's a bunch of named variables, you have to name them. If it's a `tuple`, there are useful tricks. But even your sample inputs make no sense, why is `'||'` becoming `.   .` on output?

Comment: If you have a collection of strings, where each string makes up one row (for example, `rows = ['----', '|  |', '----']`), then you could do `box = '\n'.join(rows)`, followed by `print(box)`. In this case, `box` will be the string `'----\n|  |\n----'`, which, when printed, will be printed on three lines.

Comment: @user3479780: 1) `print` is a function, not a statement anymore (it was a statement in Py2) 2) It would store a `tuple` if you did that, not a single formatted string. And it's still unclear what the OP actually wants. Output? A string that changes with the change in local variables? Something else?

Comment: Ill edit to include what I actually have put in.

Comment: @PaulM.: Or if you want to *just* print it, you don't need the joined string, `print(*rows, sep="\n")`

Comment: printing the rows worked. I just didnt realize till it was commented below on how to format it. print(*a1_map, sep="\n") worked liked a charm

Comment: You seem to be using more than just ASCII characters, if so you might want to check out https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character for some Unicode characters designed for this purpose.  Whether they will render correctly depends on the fonts the user has selected, but that's true of `\u2143` as well

Answer (score 0):

So, I feel dumb.
Formatting it and then using a loop seemed to work

```
a1_map = [north_no_exit, top_E_exit, mid_E_exit, lower_E_exit, south_exit]

for segment in a1_map:
print(segment)
```

Comment: Don't even need the loop. `print(*a1_map, sep="\n")`

Comment: Thanks! That worked and is much more clean

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `+` to join strings or string `join()` method to join them with a separator string.
You can also make a dictionary or a list to help you manage them and iterate them

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use Python's f-string.

````
north_exit = ' ___|   |___'
north_no_exit = ' ___________'
south_exit = ' ```|  |``` '
mid_no_exit = '|           |'
top_WandE_exit = '\u2143           L'
top_W_exit = '\u2143           |'
top_E_exit = '|           L'
mid_WandE_exit = '    (\u00B0.\u00B0)      '
mid_W_exit ='    (\u00B0.\u00B0)   |'
mid_E_exit ='|   (\u00B0.\u00B0)    '
lower_W_exit = '\u02E5           |'
lower_WandE_exit = 'T           T'
lower_E_exit = '|           T'
current_room = 'the crew quarters'

a1_map = f"{north_no_exit}\n{top_E_exit}\n{mid_E_exit}\n{lower_E_exit}\n{south_exit}\n"
message = "You are in',current_room."
print(a1_map+message)
````